# In the long run, right will out

Tags: phrase-request, american-english, idiom-request

There is a common proverb in our language which says: "Always someone who's right and has the right, will achieve it because it was his / her right." The only equivalent I found is:

> - In the long run, right will out.

But I doubt if first, it is natural and second it works in AmE.

I would appreciate it if someone could let me know what an AE native speaker would say here in a natural way.

Comment: There is "Truth will out".  But I have never heard "right will out".

Answer (score -1):

Time will tell.

> You could also use this with a "throw-your-hands-up-in-the-air" kind of attitude, "(Only) time will tell."